# how to use svndumpfilter to exclude a certain revision

Tags: svn, version-control, svnadmin, svndumpfilter

I have an SVN repository with a bad revision or two. I need to get rid of them! I was planning on using the svndumpfilter tool, which has an `exclude` command. However, I cannot figure out how to use it to exclude a revision. Everytime I use it, I end up with a `Malformed dumpfile header` error. See the command below; I want to exclude revision 23, and code is the directory containing the repository.

```
>svndumpfilter exclude 23 code
Excluding prefixes:
   '/23'
   '/code'

SVN-fs-dump-format-version: 2

<waits for me to type something and press enter>

'vndumpfilter: E140001: Malformed dumpfile header '
```

Comment: can you give us the exact commands you are using ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`svndumpfilter` tool uses the stdin as input and filters **only** on certain paths, so you cannot exclude a specific revision.
However you can try to dump your repository from rev 0 to rev. 22 and continue from rev 24 to HEAD, however, this will work only if no file changed in rev 23 is changed after rev 23 again.

Here a small script:

```
svnadmin dump my -r0:22 code > /path/to/dumpfile_1.dmp
svnadmin dump --incremental -r24:HEAD code > /path/to/dumpfile_2.dmp
```

If you want to create a new repository out of dumpfiles:

```
svnadmin create code_correct
svnadmin load code_correct <  /path/to/dumpfile_1.dmp 
svnadmin load code_correct <  /path/to/dumpfile_2.dmp
```

Comment: I'm forced to exclude a revision because its MD5 hash is corrupted. I'm not able to dump or svnsync.
I've found a few mailings when searching the internet describing a method for fixing this (like: [this](http://www.entropyfarm.org/things/svn-checksum-mismatch-recovery/ ), but they are not applicable for my installation as the file structure is different. ( I don't have folder structure like repos-name/db/revs/ in 1.7.9 svn)  
Do you have an alternative for that scenario?